# ASP.Net - Update controls inside an Update Panel when raising an event

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, multithreading

ASP.Net noob here trying to update a control inside an UpdatePanel inside a method subscribing to an event, with no luck.

Some background, I have written a DLL that interfaces with a standard POTS telephone and I have mapped various occurences on the phone end (phone being picked up, phone ringing etc) to .Net events.

In my ASP.Net solution, I have added my DLL, instantiated my phone and, in methods subscribing to my events I want to update various labels inside an UpdatePanel with information inside the EventArgs objects being passed into my methods.

Using breakpoints, I can see that my Phone object is functioning as expected, the events are being raised when they are supposed to and the EventArgs contain the information they are supposed to.

But the labels inside the UpdatePanel never update. I wrote the previous version of the application as a Windows Form, and I recall that whenever updating the UI from another thread, I had to check whether `InvokeRequired` was true first, and if so call the `Invoke` method but I don't know what the equivalent to this is in ASP.Net (if there is one).

Markup is below (this is just an example project I have created to get my head around the basics):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #form1
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="text-align: center" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ScriptManager1" EventName="Load" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now for the code:

```
using System;

//My DLL
using Maximiser;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //My Phone Object
        private Phone _ThisPhone { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Instantiating Phone Object with IP Address and Port
            _ThisPhone = new Phone("8.8.8.8", 8888);

            //Hookstate event indicates phone is off/on the hook
            _ThisPhone.HookState += new EventHandler<Maximiser.Events.Hookstate>(thisPhone_HookState);
        }

        void thisPhone_HookState(object sender, Maximiser.Events.Hookstate e)
        {
            //I want to update my Label with the phones current HookState
            Label1.Text = e.State;

            //Now I want to refresh the UpdatePanel but not reload the page
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

The method is definitely running as shown below:

[image: Breakpoint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imported your update panel and `thisPhone_HookState` method into a test project I made, and It worked fine. I'm starting to wonder if maybe your method is not being called. Could you try to put a break point in your method to test that out?

I would think you'd call the method like so

```
thisPhone_HookState(_ThisPhone.HookState, new EventHandler<Maximiser.Events.Hookstate>);
```

Comment: Thanks, however the method is running, I have updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: out of curiosity, can you put this in your page load to test if the update is working. 

label1.text = "testing"; updatePanel1.Update();

Comment: Well that works fine, but isn't this being called in the same thread, whereas my event runs in a second thread that has no access to the UI?

Comment: Maybe the best bet would be to just have a method that checks the hookstate with a timer.

Comment: So I would have something like an automatic property holding the HookState, then I would update the automatic property in the method subscribing to my event, then I have a `System.Web.UI.Timer` setup to regularly check the value of the property and update the label? Wouldn't this be processor intensive?

Comment: kinda, but if the threads can't access any of the UI components i don't really see any other way to do this.